# Unable to exit from watch

Tags: watch-command

I have executed

```
>> watch tree ./
```

Now my problem is I'm unable to exit from `watch` - without closing the terminal.

I read man page of `watch` but they have not mentioned how to exit from watch screen.

Is there is magic key combo that you need to use to exit from watch ?

It's like one those problems you face when you for the first time open vim and don't know how to close it.

Comment: Watch works like `tail -f`, a command to inspect realtime logfiles, for example: `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog`. It will not end, unless you type Ctrl-C

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press Ctrl-C to interrupt `watch`. Ctrl-C is the general key combination to kill the foreground process in the shell. If that fails (it sometimes does for hung processes), pressing Ctrl-Z and issuing `kill -9 %1`to kill process number one works.

If you press Ctrl-Z you can do more things:

- Resume the job to foreground by running `fg`
- Resume the job in the background running `bg`
- List running jobs using `jobs`
- Manipulate the job, as mentioned, using `kill`
- Change priority of job using `renice`
- Start new jobs, leaving the old running in the background

Comment: okay, this works. But did the `watch` developers not give way to exit from it, like what we have key - `q` for exiting from htop/top. I was looking for something like that.

Comment: It does say:  By default, watch will run until interrupted. This is unix-ese for ending it with Ctrl-C :)

Comment: * if you prefer you can make your own `watch` with a `while` loop like this: `while true; do clear; tree ./ ; read -t2.0 -s -n1 k;[[ $k == "q" ]]&&break; done` - I wrapped a custom `ps|awk` pipeline this way because "it looks like `top`" I wanted it to behave like it.

Comment: Ctrl+z or ctrl+c not working in single user Mode...